# How to make a large table responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, html-table

My tables display fine on desktop, but once I try to view the mobile version my table ends up being too wide for the mobile device screen. I am using a responsive layout.
 How can I set this table to be displayed fine in the mobile
This is my code

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="row clearfix">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="body">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="myTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover js-basic-example dataTable">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Position</th>
                                <th>Office</th>
                                <th>Age</th>
                                <th>Start date</th>
                                <th>Salary</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Position</th>
                            <th>Office</th>
                            <th>Age</th>
                            <th>Start date</th>
                            <th>Salary</th>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Check out this approach https://css-tricks.com/examples/ResponsiveTables/responsive.php

Answer (score 2):

Another option might be to enable horizontal scrolling for the table by adding overflow-x:auto; to the stylesheet for the parent div.

```
div.table-responsive {
  overflow-x:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to fight fisics, my friends. Maybe you can hide the less important columns using media queries, show 3 instead of 6